# IF my id contain any meta character append '\\' before that meta character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need javascript function that checks my variable if it contains any special character then append '\' before that special character:

```
function escapeStr(str) {
            var specChar = /([ !"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~])/;
            if (str.match(specChar))
                return str.replace('+special character+', '\\'+special character+'');
            else
                return str;
        }
```

Comment: acctually these str are the ids of html control i want to put \\ just before that special character

Comment: You don't need `.match' because `.replace` already searches for a match between a substring (or regular expression) and a string, and replaces the matched substring with a new substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a regexp to `String.replace`, and you're using parenthesis blocks already, so you can reference to your special character in the replace string. Additionally, if you add the global flag at the end of the regexp, it'll go through all of them, not just the first find.

```
function escapeStr(str) {
    var specChar = /([ !"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~])/g;
    return str.replace(specChar, '\\$1');
}
```

Calling `escapeStr("Hello & World!")` would return `"Hello\ \&\ World\!"`;

Comment: acctually these str are the ids of html control i want to put \\ just before that special character

Comment: I would really try to avoid such a thing for id's. It's impractical and it'll likely cause you trouble or cause unexpected results.

Comment: Can you please tell what is $1? @MildlyInteresting

Comment: In a regexp, if you place part of it in parenthesis `()` you are creating a group which you can reference in the replace string. In your case, that's the special character. So in the replace string, you are referencing to your special characters after the backslashes.

Comment: Thanks alot it did work for this type of string code as well "AB%N.MH*HT^KLI#NJH89KI)JK"
http://jsfiddle.net/u9nG6/161/